# Turbolinks and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I can't submit my post without refreshing edit page, I am using turbolinks gem and simple_form here is the source code:

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-lg-9 col-md-8">  
  <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>

    <div class = "form-group">

    <%= f.input :title, :label => false %>
    <%= f.input :content, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'MyToolbar', :height => 465} } %>
    <%= f.input :cat_list, :label => "Type your tags here" %>

    </div>


<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
 </div>
 <div class = "col-lg-3 col-md-4 ">
 <div class = "form-group" data-no-turbolink >
    <p>
    <%= image_tag(@post.thumbnail.url(:original), :class => "img-thumbnail") %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.select :tag_list, Post::Months, { }, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => "form-control" } %>
    </p>
        <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How are you submitting the second form?

Comment: and where is the form_for tag?

Comment: It's just 1 submit button, I tried to move it down to 2 form and when I press it there it does't submit anything, but when I reload page, form submits successfully.

Comment: Oh seems I found my error, but now I have another - I can't send form without refreshing page with turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I have misunderstood your problem.

**By default, Turbolinks works only for GET requests.**

So, in your case, you are not using turbolinks to submit the page.

Notice the `data-no-turbolink` attribute added to `<div class = "form-group">`

`<div class = "form-group" data-no-turbolink >
    <p>
    <%= image_tag(@post.thumbnail.url(:original), :class => "img-thumbnail") %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.select :tag_list, Post::Months, { }, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => "form-control" } %>
    </p>
        <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </p>
 </div>`

Whenever turbolinks finds a `data-no-turbolink` attribute, it ensures that all anchor tags within it fallback to the default behavior **i.e. ignore turbolinks**

The 'edit' page however may have been rendered using turbolinks.